# Need to tally certain items on HTML page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Storytime.

So, I have this HTML code:

```
<tr valign="top" class="">
    <td class="col-status status-yellow">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="col-chk"><input name="ctl00" type="checkbox" class="checklistitem" title="Not Applicable" value="40" /></td>
    <td class="col-chk"><input name="ctl00" type="checkbox" class="checklistitem" title="Fixed" value="40" /></td>
    <td class="col-chk"><input name="ctl00" type="checkbox" class="checklistitem" title="OK" value="40" /></td>
    <td class="col-flag flag-red"><input name="ctl00" type="hidden" id="ctl00" value="True" /></td>
    <td class="col-question">8 (40).<a href="#" onclick="ChecklistNavigate('photos');return false;">link</a> <a href="#" onclick="showComments('40', 'ctl00');return false;">notes</a><input name="ctl00" type="hidden" id="ctl00" /></td>
</tr>

<tr valign="top" class="">
    <td class="col-status status-yellow">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="col-chk"><input name="ctl00" type="checkbox" class="checklistitem" title="Not Applicable" value="380" /></td>
    <td class="col-chk"><input name="ctl00" type="checkbox" class="checklistitem" title="Fixed" value="380" /></td>
    <td class="col-chk"><input name="ctl00" type="checkbox" class="checklistitem" title="OK" value="380" /></td>
    <td class="col-flag flag-notset"><input name="ctl00" type="hidden" id="ctl00" value="True" /></td>
    <td class="col-question">23 (380).<a href="#" onclick="ChecklistNavigate('photos');return false;">link</a> <a href="#" onclick="showComments('380', 'ctl00');return false;">notes</a><input name="ctl00" type="hidden" id="ctl00" /></td>
</tr>

<tr valign="top" class="">
    <td class="col-status status-yellow">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="col-chk"><input name="ctl00" type="checkbox" class="checklistitem" title="Not Applicable" value="20" /></td>
    <td class="col-chk"><input name="ctl00" type="checkbox" class="checklistitem" title="Fixed" value="20" /></td>
    <td class="col-chk"><input name="ctl00" type="checkbox" class="checklistitem" title="OK" value="20" /></td>
    <td class="col-flag flag-red"><input name="ctl00" type="hidden" id="ctl00" value="True" /></td>
    <td class="col-question">6 (20).<a href="#" onclick="ChecklistNavigate('photos');return false;">link</a> <a href="#" onclick="showComments('20', 'ctl00');return false;">notes</a><input name="ctl00" type="hidden" id="ctl00" /></td>
</tr>
```

Well, that's only a small amount of the code. There are around 100 of these blocks (or, "questions" as I call them). In the example above, there are 3 questions: question 40, 380, and 20.

**What I am looking for** is a count of the flagged questions. In the example above, there are two flagged questions: 40 and 20. This is indicated by the attribute "flag-red". What I have so far is:

```
var flaggedRed2 = document.getElementsByClassName("flag-red");
window.alert(flaggedRed2.length);
```

And this works. However! Now, the tricky part: **What I am *really* looking for** is a count of flagged question, but only from certain questions. For example, I don't care about question 40 (or a number of other questions, for that matter). I want to ignore that one. I want the window alert to say: 1.

Is this possible? As you can see, the "flag-red" class doesn't have the question number associated with it, like the other classes in each "tr" do. And, unfortunately, I can't add it to the HTML code.

Thank you in advance to anyone who may have some insight.

Comment: What is the condition that you are referring to ?

Comment: You could use regular expressions to pull the question number out of the actual text and then compare it with a preset list.

Comment: I should have mentioned this: I'm a total n00b. I have no clue what to do. The fact that I've gotten this far is a miracle.

Comment: Get all `<tr>` elements and then iterate through them discarding the ones that are not `red-flag` and those that you don't want (question #).

Comment: P.S. you are making things harder on yourself by giving the page elements the same id and name attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look here, using jquery: http://jsbin.com/opesok/1/edit

**code**

```
  var ignored = [40];
  //var ignored = [40, 20];    //another example
  var redFlagTotal = 0;

  $(".flag-red").each(function(){
    var re = /\((.*?)\)/;
    var text = re.exec($(this).siblings(".col-question").text())[1];
    if(ignored.indexOf(parseInt(text)) < 0)
      redFlagTotal++;
  });
  alert("Tot: "+redFlagTotal)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a version without jQuery, I have a jsFiddle that should work.

http://jsfiddle.net/BradleyStaples/dmvXM/

```
var rejectQuestions = function(flagged, rejections) {

    var i = 0,
        flaggedLength = flagged.length,
        rejectionsLength = rejections.length,
        n = 0,
        questionNumber = null;
    flagged2 = nodeListToArray(flagged);

    for (i = 0; i < flaggedLength; i++) {
        questionNumber = flagged[i].previousSibling.previousSibling.querySelector('input').value;
        for (n = 0; n < rejectionsLength; n++) {
            if (rejections[n] === questionNumber) {
                flagged2.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    return flagged2;
};

var nodeListToArray = function(nodeList){
    var arry = [],
        i = 0,
        len = nodeList.length;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        arry.push(nodeList[i]);
    }
    return arry;
};

var flaggedQuestions = document.querySelectorAll('.flag-red'),
    rejections = ['40'],
    filteredQuestions = rejectQuestions(flaggedQuestions, rejections);

console.log(filteredQuestions);
```

One thing of note - the returned value is an actual array, not a nodeList, so you'll need to take that into account.